# How to fix this Intellisense error (XContainer::Element)

Tags: linq, c++-cli

The code bellow generates an error and I don't know how to fix it:

```
XElement^ root = XElement.Load("data.xml");
String^ location;
location = root->Element("location")->Value;
```

This is the error:

*IntelliSense: no instance of function "System::Xml::Linq::XElement::Element" matches the argument list
argument types are: (const char [10])*

*object type is: System::Xml::Linq::XElement ^*

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`XElement` does have an [`Element` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.element(v=vs.110).aspx), but it takes an `XName` as its sole parameter, not a char array. Pass an `XName` instance instead of `"location"` and the error should disappear.

Comment: Does C++/CLI not handle the implicit conversion from `string` to `XName` then?

Comment: @JonSkeet: Obviously not, but I could very well be wrong. (Do you mean [because of this implicit conversion operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xname.op_implicit(v=vs.110).aspx)? This should work if the argument were of type `String^`, but it's a `char[]`.)  I hardly know C++/CLI, so my answer shouldn't be taken as gospel.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the literal to a variable of type String^ and it worked. It's weird because I saw several C++/CLI examples on the internet and their use of Element was like mine. MSDN doesn't have a C++/CLI example for that method.